# How to iterate through a list of unknown type in JAVA

Tags: java, generics, generic-programming, generic-collections

I have 2 lists of Generic type.

```
List1 of type Generic_Class1

List2 of type Generic_Class2
```

I want to iterate through above lists in single for each loop.

like,

```
for(Generic_Class loop_variable: List1/List2){

}
```

Is it possible to do in JAVA?

Comment: If you don't know what `T` is, you can probably only call methods from class `Object`.

Comment: `Generic_Class` could be `Object`

Comment: If `Generic_Class1` and `Generic_Class2` have a common type `Generic_Class` or an interface you could use this type.

Comment: Yes, in Generic_Class I can use as object, but I can not access the fields of Generic_Class1/Generic_Class2 in the loop as this loop variable will be the Object not the Generic_Class1/Generic_Class2.

Comment: You can then cast the loop_variable into Generic_Class1/Generic_Class2

Comment: Do you want to iterate over both lists at the same time? So in every iteration you want to have an element from `List1` and `List2`?

Comment: Consider a function iterate, which iterates a list of any type. 
iterate(list of type 1){
for (Object var : list){
}
}
this function should be generic that means, the for loop can handle any list of the any type.

as mentioned i comments if I used object as for loop type, I cannot access the fields of that class.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to iterate over both lists at the same time and if your `Generic_Class1` and `Generic_Class2` both extends Generic_Class you can do something like this :

```
List<Generic_Class> genericList = new ArrayList<Generic_Class>(list1);
genericList.addAll(list2);
for(Generic_Class loop_variable: genericList){
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't say the for-loop iterates over both lists _at the same time_. It does it in sequence. That's why I [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52737548/how-to-iterate-through-a-list-of-unknown-type-in-java#comment92400285_52737548). But still this could be an answer.